# Subtract two date fields using computed twig in Drupal 10

Tags: drupal

Would be grateful for some assistance on this.

I am building a webform using the webforms module in Drupal 10 and I want to subtract two date fields and as a result display the difference between the dates.

For example,

```
{{ 2024-01-11 - 2024-01-10 }} = {TheDifferenceInDays}.
```

Thanks

I have tried using the following expression in my computed twig field however this is returning a value of 0 - is that because the date fields need to be in a specific format?

```
{{ date1 -  date2 }}
```

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260658/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-webform